# phpmyadmin showing error #1064 alter table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
ALTER TABLE Role ADD CONSTRAINT fk_role FOREIGN KEY (user_position_idposition) REFERENCES position(idposition)
```

table position it looks like :

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `position` (
  `idposition` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nmposition` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `organization_idorganization` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `levelposition` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

and Role looks like :

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Role` (
  `idRole` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `namerole` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_position_idposition` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_employee_nik` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

when i try to do like this it will not result as expected,Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show a `describe tablename` for the tables `role` and `position`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `Query` must be like this

```
ALTER TABLE `Role`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_position_idposition) REFERENCES `position` (`idposition`)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

NOTE: `idposition` must be `unique` and it should be a `primary key`

Answer (score 0):

Foriegn key always references primary key or unique...so make change in position table and make "idposition" field as unique or primary key